# Rails 3: Check for routing error in rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a lot of courses in my website. I have a "go to course" form. When user inputs a valid course name, I successfully redirect that user to that course page.

```
 def courses
    @title = "Courses"
    @path  = "#{root_path}"+"course/" + "#{params[:course]}"
    if @path == "/course/"
        @title = "Courses"
        render 'courses'
    else 
        redirect_to @path
    end
end
```

This works for all valid inputs that is if the route exists. I want to take care of the error case when the user inputs invalid course name which would cause an invalid route. I want to check for routing error in the code and let the user know with an error message. Is this possible?"

Comment: Why don't you query your database to see if it's a valid course before redirecting?

Comment: why are ou building your routes that way? why not use routes instead? it seems you're "going against the framework".

Comment: each course page is just a static page.. I implemented it this way because originally i have very few courses like 5 but now i have a lot. I think i will just implement a new controller

Comment: I followed Jeff's advice, I stored all the names of the courses in the database. And before redirecting i query the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of building out custom routes in your controller, use Rails convention and place them in config/routes.rb:

```
    resources :courses
```

This creates the route /courses/:id for you. Then your controller would simplify to:

```
    def show
      @title = "Courses"
    end
```

It would help if you included your model, controller and routes.rb.

Comment: i don't have a model or anything.. The courses are just static pages and i manually assigned routes to them in config/routes.rb

Comment: I recommend using the MVC architecture that Rails is based off of or picking another framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to check if your route is valid:

```
def check_route(route)

    @route_valid = true
    begin
        ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(@route, :method => :get)
    rescue
        # error means that your route is not valid, so do something to remember that here
        @route_valid = false
    end
end
```

But in general, I do not like your idea of creating a route based on a course. Why not just use a simple finder?

Comment: yes you are right, I am still learning rails. Getting used to it. I am not following this logic anymore. I created a database of courses and i query the database before redirecting the user